# Postgres: Group by on a column but query needs to return all columns in the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have table that has following structure:

```
id, user_id, connected_id, completed
1, 2345, 232, t
2, 2345, 121, f
3, 4324, 123, t
4, 4324, 121, t
5, 1211, 134, f
6, 1211, 111, t
```

Is there a way to do get all columns of the table group by `user_id`. Since column that I `group by` has to be in the clause. Is there a work around.

I was trying to construct following result set:

```
user_id, total_completed
```

I thought I would do a two stage process, since I am actually accessing data via `mybatis`.

Comment: get the group by first and join main query with that. BTW, what you are trying to do? you may want post desired result as well.

Comment: So what `connected_id` are you expecting to see for the `user_id = 2345`?

Comment: What is `total_completed`?

Comment: @zerkms aggregation of completed rows per user_id

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: what do you exactly mean by "aggregation of completed rows"?

Comment: @zerkms for each user_id how many completed are there? is what I was trying to get at.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: what is "total"? Do you mean "count"?

Comment: @zerkms yes count of completed

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you need is

```
  SELECT user_id,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN completed THEN 1 END) total_completed
    FROM tablename
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `GROUP BY`, the output columns must either be columns that you grouped on or can be aggregation functions.  To understand why, think about grouping by `user_id` in your example data.  If you try to output the column `connected_id`, what value should that column contain in the row for `user_id=2345`?  There are two values, 232 from the first row and 121 from the second row.  You must choose how to handle the multiple values.  You have several options:

- Add `connected_id` to the `GROUP_BY` clause.  This will give you one row of output for `user_id=2345, connected_id=232` and one row of output for `user_id=2345, connected_id=121`

```
   user_id  connected_id

   2345     232       
   2345     121       
   4324     123       
   4324     121       
   1211     134       
   1211     111
```

- Use the aggregation function `array_agg(connected_id)`.  This will give you all the values as an array:

```
    user_id  array_of_connected_id

    2345     {232, 121}
    4324     {123, 121}
    1211     {134, 111}
```

- Use a math function like `max(connected_id)`:

```
    user_id  max_of_connected_id

    2345     232
    4324     123
    1211     134
```

Since there can be multiple values, you have to be explicit about how to handle those multiple values.  For your specific case, the answer from @zerkms will give what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user_id) t.*
from mytable t
order by user_id;
```

This will return an arbitrary row for each `user_id`.